# Url requests not working while the flask app is hosted

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, https, python-requests

I have a flask web app running a just-dial scraper code, In my code, I have to request multiple pages of the Justdial site to use it in the bs4 module to extract the data and fill it in the excel sheet. I use `requests.Session()` to do the process.

```
            session = requests.Session()
            session.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"})
            url=f"{entry}/page-{page_number}"
            session.verify = False
            r = session.get(url).text
```

Then this "r" is passed into the `bs4` module and the extraction process takes place.

Whenever I run this code in the local host my program works fine, the data is getting extracted and the values are getting stored in the excel file. But when I host this as webapp in `heroku` and try the same process in `heroku`, I am not getting the desired output, there are no errors shown in `except` and `try` as well. Also I am getting empty excel file as output.

I tried using `Urllib`, `requests.get()` and also `requests.get(url, verify-False)` but the same problem exists.

This warning pops up while i run the program in localhost

> /home/disciple/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:846: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
> warnings.warn((

Comment: If we host app on heroku https is enabled, you can use it. And see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted&ved=2ahUKEwjh3MeY94_xAhV-6XMBHdXJCAEQFjAAegQIDRAC&usg=AOvVaw3NjxAanHnKWMeK61UBgGcV), you should not save data in excel file.

Comment: Actually there are no problems with excel file, infact excel file getting refreshed on every run is a benefit, the problem is not running past the requests at all is the issue : (